# Getting HTML table cell width in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

I am trying to create a HTML table and get cell width in Qt.

I created a HTML table:

```
QString css;
css = "<style type=\"text/css\">";
css += "table.tbl {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;color: black;}";
css += "table.tbl td {padding: 3px;}";
css += "table.tbl th {padding: 3px;}";
css+="</style>";

QString text;
text="<table width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"tbl\">";
text+=("<tr><th>1</th><th colspan=\"2\">2</th><th>3</th><th></th></tr>");
text+=("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>");
text+=("<tr><td colspan=\"2\">4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>");
text+=("<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>");
text+=("<tr><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr></table>");
```

I need width of specific cell. I found a JavaScript function for getting cell width:

```
document.getElementById('tblID').rows[0].cells[0].offsetWidth
```

But I do not know how can I use it in Qt.

Comment: Do you need to push the width back to some C++ code?  You'll probably want to use the hybrid/WebKit facilities for that.  You'll still use that javascript bit then emit it back to the C++ with a signal.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look at using Qt Objects in a QWebFrame.  You'll probably want to start here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject

Qt supports messaging between C++ code and javascript objects through the signals and slots as well as properties.